# a tricky ssrs question

Tags: reporting-services

I have a `ssrs report`. There is a matrix with 2 row groups(from outer to inner): group - item, and 1 column group: year. I hope it's fairly easy to understand. Please refer to below "image".

```
Group         CAGR                  2010                        2011                                             

Group1        CAGR_group1     sum_group1_2010     sum_group1_2011
     Item1     CAGR_item1       sum_item1_2010       sum_item1_2011
     Item2     CAGR_item2       sum_item2_2010       sum_item2_2011
```

The `sum_group1_2010` and `sum_group1_2011` are sum of item1 and item2 for each year.
`CAGR_item1` and `CAGR_item2` are calculated by this fomular:

```
CAGR = (sum_item2_2011/sum_item2_2010)^(1/n) - 1 (n=2011-2010)
```

I created this function in code. It's simple to calculate CAGR for each item. I used following expression: note First refer to 2010, and last refer to 2011 in this case.

```
Code.CAGR(First(Fields!Amount.Value).ToString, Last(Fields!Amount.Value).ToString, Last(Fields!year.Value).ToString - First(Fields!year.Value).ToString)
```

Now the problem is how can I calculate for the CAGR_group1? I intended to use

```
Code.CAGR(First(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)).ToString, Last(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)).ToString, Last(Fields!year.Value).ToString - First(Fields!year.Value).ToString).
```

Then SSRS reported can not use aggregate function in another aggregate function.

Hope it's all clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to add the calculation to your SQL query: it could be a new column in your existing query, which calculates to the same value for every record(row). Then in your report just use the FIRST function.

Alternately, this may work if you add appropriate scope statements to your aggregate functions, such as FIRST(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "ItemGroupName") , "Group1GroupName")

Comment: I finally used sql to do all the calculation and let SSRS just to display the results. Btw i used SSRS2008. The FIRST(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value, "ItemGroupName") , "Group1GroupName") apporach also doesn't work as "The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group...".